# Can not get shadow document data

Tags: amazon-web-services

- I've gone though [Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html) and [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/index.html)
- I've checked [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-php-sdk) for answers

**Version of AWS SDK for PHP**
v3.209.10

**Version of PHP**
7.3.8

**Describe the question**
I am using AWS SDK for IotDataPlaneClient, I have successfully created the client. I have also successfully retrieved the list of shadows using **ListNamedShadowsForThing** as well as updated the shadow document using **updateThingShadow**. But I am failing to get the state saved in the Shadow Document. I have used following code

```
use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$thing_name = "MY_THING_NAME";
$shadow_name = "MY_SHADOW_NAME";
$public_key = "MY_PUBLIC_KEY";
$private_key = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";

$client = new Aws\IotDataPlane\IotDataPlaneClient([
    'endpoint' => 'MY_ENDPOINT',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
    //'tls'  => false,
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $public_key,
        'secret' => $private_key,
    ],
]);

try{
    $result1 = $client->getThingShadow([
        'thingName' => $thing_name,
        'shadowName' => $shadow_name,
    ]);

    print "<pre>"; 
    print_r($result);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

I am getting only **payload** and **@metadata** in the result, but not the state in my document. I have tried a lot of things but can not find anything.

```
What I am doing wrong?
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally. All I had to do is **json_decode** the **payload**. So my updated code is like the following

```
use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$thing_name = "MY_THING_NAME";
$shadow_name = "MY_SHADOW_NAME";
$public_key = "MY_PUBLIC_KEY";
$private_key = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";

$client = new Aws\IotDataPlane\IotDataPlaneClient([
    'endpoint' => 'MY_ENDPOINT',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
    //'tls'  => false,
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $public_key,
        'secret' => $private_key,
    ],
]);

try{
    $result1 = $client->getThingShadow([
        'thingName' => $thing_name,
        'shadowName' => $shadow_name,
    ]);
    
    $payload = json_decode($result['payload']);

    print "<pre>"; 
    print_r($payload);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```